# Why does Fortran 90 compilation takes very long when large static array are initialized?

Tags: arrays, compilation, fortran, initialization

I need to initialize an static array in a Fortran subroutine

```
double precision A(56136,8)
```

like so:

```
  A(1,1)=0.999950528145
  A(1,2)=0.99982470274
  A(1,3)=0.999987006187
  .
  .
  .
  A(56136,7)=0.933468163013
  A(56136,8)=0.0668926686049
```

The latter is generated by another program.

Compilation with ifort 13.0 `ifort file.f -O0` takes very long (around 30 minutes).

**Q1:** What is the reason for this and how can I avoid it?

I have no handle on the main program, the subroutine is linked to third party files. The subroutine is called very often, so file access is not desirable.

**Q2:** Can I put the initialization outside the subroutine, without having a main program, avoiding the initialization every time the subroutine is called?

**Edit**

It is constant. Initializing it in the declaration statement would look like this?

```
  double precision A(56136:8)=reshape(/*
 &             #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #,
 &             #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #,
 :
 &            */,(56136,8))
```

This does not work because there are too many newlines.

Comment: Because the compiler has a lot work to do. Can't you initialize it in the declaration statement? Is it a constant or will it change later?

Comment: It is constant. Initializing it in the declaration statement would look like this?
      double precision A(56136:8)=reshape(/*
     &             #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #,
     &             #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #,
     :
     &        */,(56136,8))
Is that correct?

Comment: If it is constant why not make it a parameter?

Comment: I would not have imagined that it is so hard to initialize a large array.

Comment: The code is crazee, it includes nearly 450,000 lines of assignment statements.  The compiler probably sits there stunned for about 25 minutes going *WTF ?*, then buckles down and gets on with the job.  Are you sure you can't modify the code to read the values from a file when first needed, and use `save` to keep them around between calls ?

Comment: i am working on it right now but it is tedious

Comment: Thanks, your hint with the `save` statement saved my day. Apart from that is there a place where i can rant against Fortran safely?

Comment: I would read it from a file instead and keep it in memory. There is only one file access needed.

Comment: Have you tried with `DATA` statements, and if there are too many line continuations, splitting it up to several arrays, only to be assembled later.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. I did it by reading the data from a file once and keeping it by help of the save keyword. Putting it into the source code did not work because of too many newlines (declaration) or excessive compiler work (assigning in the code)

Comment: @ChristianSchmidt you saw the light. I am glad my suggestion of file retrieval worked out for you.

Comment: *is there a place where i can rant against Fortran safely ?*  Almost any tech meetup where the average age is under 60 (ie almost any tech meetup).  Me, I like to rant about Swift and .NET and other toy programming languages ...

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fortran

Comment: Do you know that Fortran means "Formula Translator"? It is not a programming language at all, its a translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test with 10000 integers and it compiles in seconds when using a `DATA` statement. My array holds 50000 integers but wanted to see if I can assign them in blocks of 10000.

```fortran
program Console1
implicit none
! Variables
integer A(50000)

data A(1:10000) / &       ! 1000 lines of 10 numbers each to follow:
      2,     3,     5,     7,    11,    13,    17,    19,    23,    29, &
     31,    37,    41,    43,    47,    53,    59,    61,    67,    71, &
     73,    79,    83,    89,    97,   101,   103,   107,   109,   113, &
    127,   131,   137,   139,   149,   151,   157,   163,   167,   173, &
    179,   181,   191,   193,   197,   199,   211,   223,   227,   229, &
    233,   239,   241,   251,   257,   263,   269,   271,   277,   281, &
...
 104087,104089,104107,104113,104119,104123,104147,104149,104161,104173, &
 104179,104183,104207,104231,104233,104239,104243,104281,104287,104297, &
 104309,104311,104323,104327,104347,104369,104381,104383,104393,104399, &
 104417,104459,104471,104473,104479,104491,104513,104527,104537,104543, &
 104549,104551,104561,104579,104593,104597,104623,104639,104651,104659, &
 104677,104681,104683,104693,104701,104707,104711,104717,104723,104729 /

! Append the first 10000 elements to the remaining array
A(10001:50000) = [A(1:10000),A(1:10000),A(1:10000),A(1:10000)]

print *, A(9998:10002)

end program Console1
```

---

**Edit 1**

Here is how do use a `DATA` statement with a `COMMON` block to set the values inside a subroutine. Note that use of common blocks is *nearly* deprecated.

```fortran
subroutine A_Fill()
implicit none
integer :: A(10)
common /vals/ A
data A/ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 /

end subroutine

program Console1
implicit none
! Variables
integer :: A(10)
common /vals/ A

call A_Fill()
print *, A

end program Console1
```

---

**Edit 2**

Another solution that uses a function to copy the saved array into a secondary working copy.

```
function A_Fill() result(B)
implicit none
integer :: B(10)
integer,save :: A(10)
data A/ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 /
    B = A
end function

program Console1
implicit none   
interface 
    function A_Fill() result(B)
    implicit none
    integer :: B(10)
    end function        
end interface
! Variables
integer :: A(10)

A = A_Fill()    
print *, A

end program Console1
```

Comment: Your comment on the question ("Have you tried with DATA statements, and if there are too many line continuations, splitting it up to several arrays, only to be assembled later.") suggests it may be worth stating: several data statements can be used to initialize a single array.

Comment: @francescalus Yes, you can use a `DATA` statement to initialize only part of an array (like I have done) and chain several statements to fully define a big array. See the documentation for `DATA` for the three main options (by name, by element, or by implied do loop).

Comment: I have used another solution but this answers my question. Just one thing: does it make a difference the `DATA` solution is used in `program` or `subroutine`?

Comment: @ChristianSchmidt - The `DATA` statement cannot be with a dummy argument. You have to use it with either a module variable or some other global variable (like a common block).

Comment: @ChristianSchmidt - Thank you, for the accept. I edited the answer to show how to use a subroutine to fill values using a common block.

Comment: @ChristianSchmidt, you may indeed use a data statement to initialize a local variable of a subroutine (subject to conditions which apply also to a variable of a main program).  Although, as noted by ja72, a dummy argument is not a local variable of the subroutine.

Comment: Your subroutine `A_fill` of the first edit is not valid: because `A` is in a common block it may be initialized only in a block data program unit.

Comment: @francescalus - I tested it with Intel Fortran 2017 and it compiled without warnings or errors and worked as expected on runtime.

Comment: There's a numbered constraint (C567 in F2008) prohibiting this, so the compiler should have the capability to detect violation.  nagfor, for example, will reject this code.