# Improving fortran compiler performance (Compile time and memory)

Tags: performance, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I have a cross platform project built with cmake and make or visual studio with primarily Fortran source code. The source files vary in size from on the order of 1000 lines (10s to 100s of KB) to the largest being 31000 (1.3MB) lines. However, the compile time is around 20 minutes even when parallelized with `make -jN`. There are 14 modules which are ultimately imported AND linked to build the final executable. The modules can be statically or dynamically linked. Its the final step that takes all the time: compiling the source files for the executable and linking with the module libraries. I'm using gfortran (gcc@7.3) and ifort (intel 2017) compilers.

The 31,000-line file mentioned above is imported in the executable source code, not in any of the underlying libraries. I've tried breaking up the executable source into smaller files although they are relatively small to begin with. However, the executable source does ultimately import a substantial portion of the libraries which are linked. I also tried importing only the portions of large libraries that are required rather than everything. For example, I've replaced this `USE ModuleSubs` with this `USE ModuleSubs, ONLY: ElemOpen` in a few modules, but it hasn't made a difference in compile speed yet. That being said, this is tough to time accurately since I'm changing different files every time meaning that each compile attempt is different than the one before.

On a few systems (e.g. cygwin and a docker container), the fortran compiler runs out of memory and aborts with this error:

`f951: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes after a total of 2601426944 bytes`

This error always happens at the executable compile step.

I want to understand what factors cause slow compile times and eat up memory during the compile step.

Comment: You should really tell us more about your setup, otherwise your question is too broad and hence off-topic. What size are your source files? Does any file in particular take a lot of time? Or does linking take a lot of time? Which compiler version do you use? Which compiler flags do you use? On which operating system? Do you have long module cascades? Sometimes a compiler bug can can cause excessive compilation times, but these cannot be identified without a [mcve]. Please address all the points, do not just select one or two.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks for the response, I updated the question. What do you consider "long" for a module cascade, a couple of subsequent imports or more like 5-10? I will try to generate a graph of my projects import chain so I can tell you exactly.

Comment: I meant more than a couple. There are certain issues that can make problems and you can find some of them by searching here. But those mostly concern individual source files. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709501/why-does-fortran-90-compilation-takes-very-long-when-large-static-array-are-init

Comment: As it turns out, building in debug mode avoids the `out of memory` error. So I guess that points to the optimizations being the memory hog? An answer on the module cascades coming soon.

Comment: Yes, that is quite possible. Now try to find out which optimizations do that and in which file. Or are they the link-time optimizations?